# CSS: How to keep z axis while rotating an element

Tags: html, css

I have a rotated circle element and I want to apply an animation to this element so it can get closer. But when I try to apply `translateZ` to the element, the element moves vertically. And without rotating the element, it actually can get closer when applying `translateZ`. So I am guessing the z axis is also rotating and the element moves vertically.
How can I fix this?

Code is lie below.

`html`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

`css`

```
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
  animation: moveCircle 1s linear 0s forwards;

  @keyframes moveCircle {
    to {
      transform: rotateX(60deg) translateZ(100px);
    }
  }
}
```

Expected:

[image]

Current:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?? Let me know

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:50px;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: moveCircle 2s linear 0s forwards;
}
  @keyframes moveCircle {
   from {
        transform:scale(.5) rotateX(60deg);        
        
    }
    to {
       transform: scale(1.5) rotateX(60deg);
        
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah it is the current result I mentioned on my question (the circle moves vertically). I want to move the circle to come closer.

Comment: I edited the code Is this what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is have the circle rotated about its x axis but move its wrapper towards the viewer on the z-axis - the wrapper's z axis still being perpendicular to the screen.

So this snippet sets the perspective on a container, does not animate the circle itself but moves a z translation animation to the wrapper so that will come direct out of the screen and the whole thing 'get closer'.

```css
.container {
  perspective: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(0px);
  animation: moveWrapper 1s linear 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes moveWrapper {
  to {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
  }
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```